# Why there is no search feature in the Review - Triage?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, triage

I would like to help in separating questions into categories in the Review -> Triage section, but there is no search feature where I can search for a question in order to decide it is duplicate or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're expected to triage questions according to their quality, not according to topic, or according to whether or not they are duplicates. You don't need to search for anything in order to determine the quality of a question.

Even if you really wanted to flag a question as a duplicate, the search bar is still there for you to use. But as searching removes you from the review page, you might as well evaluate it based on its quality instead. That, really, is the whole purpose of triage.